# Background job does not seem to run

Tags: powershell

I have function in a powershell 2.0 script that I am launching as a bkground job

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {CopyDataToServer($uploadSessionGuid)} -Name $uploadSessionGuid
```

Then at the end of the script I have

```
Wait-Job -State Running -Timeout $LogCopyTimeout
```

Event though the job is showing as Running and then completed, nothing is copied to the server.

How can I debug this?

Comment: A silly question: does `CopyDataToServer($uploadSessionGuid)` work itself, i.e. without using a job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roman is right about CopyDataToServer and $uploadSessionGuid probably not being defined in the runspace the job executes in (upvoted his answer).  BTW I believe it is better to wait on a specific job object than for any job in the running state e.g.:

```
$job = Start-Job {param($path, $guid) . $path\lib.ps1; CopyDataToServer $guid} `
       -arg $pwd,$uploadSessionGuid
Wait-Job $job
Receive-Job $job
```

Note that you can use the `-ArgumentList` parameter to pass in parameters to your scriptblock.  While you can access these arguments in your scriptblock via `$args`, I prefer using a param block and naming the args.  This example also shows how you can pass in the path to a PowerShell script containing the function CopyDataToServer which gets dot sourced into the job's runspace.

Answer (score 4):

The script block `{CopyDataToServer($uploadSessionGuid)}` is invoked in a new runspace where the command `CopyDataToServer` or the variable `$uploadSessionGuid` might be not available. To check this instead of your job run this at first:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    Get-Command CopyDataToServer
    Get-Variable uploadSessionGuid
}

Wait-Job -State Running
Get-Job | Receive-Job
```

If the job returns the command and the variable then the problem is elsewhere and debugging is not over. But if it fails or gets wrong results then this is the problem to be fixed (to make the command available and/or use a different way to supply the parameter).